# Including text at the end of every post

Tags: posts, templates

I would like to include some text at the end of every post. Like how some people write "Like my posts? Follow me on twitter!" or something like that. There are some buttons for users to tweet or share the posts, but I want to see how people would respond to explicit suggestions.

I thought maybe I can just copy-paste it over and over again, but if I ever decide to change it, I'd have to update every one of them, so that isn't a very scalable solution.

I also have existing posts that I wish to have this text appear.

I'm thinking of changing the theme so that each post has the text, but that doesn't seem like a very "wordpress" way to do it.

What is a good way to accomplish this? Being able to choose which posts have the text or not (eg: based on category, tags, etc.) would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter, to *append*/*prepend* text to the post content.

Here's a simple example:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {

    if( is_single() && has_tag( 'follow-me-on-twitter' ) )
    {
        $content .= '<div>Like my posts? Follow me on twitter!</div>';
    }
    return $content;

}, 99 );
```

where we append the extra text if the current single post has the `follow-me-on-twitter` tag.

Other ideas:

- You can do something similar for categories with the [`has_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) function.
- You might consider adding an [extra taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) to your posts, that's not visible on your site, to handle the markings. Then you need [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) instead.
- You can use the post meta (custom fields) to mark each post. Maybe add a [meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) with a select box.
- ...

Answer (score 1):

What is referred to as a "template part" seems to fit exactly your need here.

[WP Template Part ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Simply write up the snippet that produces the message you would like to repeat in a php file and call it with `<?php get_template_part( $slug, $name ); ?>`